# logic errors in scripts

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

```
#!/bin/bash
whilenum=1
while [ $whilenum -lt 5 ]
do 

if  [ $whilenum == 1 ]
then
function funct1 {
echo The value of whilenum is $whilenum
}
funct1 
else break
fi

if (( $whilenum == 2 | $whilenum == 3 ))
then
for animal in dog bird turtle
do
echo $animal
done
fi  

if [ $whilenum == 4 ]
then
echo Enter your name
read username
fi

if [ ${#username} >  8 ]
then
echo User name is long
else
echo User name is short

fi

whilenum=$(( $whilenum+1 ))
done
```

When I adjust the number to test the number nothing happens
I made the while loop increment so it can terminate but not sure if its working. Not getting any syntax errors probably have a few logic errors

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are breaking if whilenum is not equal to 1. Therefore, your script will not continue. I think you should remove the `else break` and you should be able to find that it works.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax works, but you are missing things because you don't indent your code.
The break is done when `whilenum -eq 1` and the `${#username}` is checked every loop.
Be aware `if  [ $whilenum == 1 ]` looks for a string `"1"`, use `-eq` or `if (( $whilenum == 1 ))`.

You did try to write code and learn, so I hope you will study the code beneath.
Your code can be improved with a `for-loop` and a `case` statement:

```
function funct1 {
   echo The value of whilenum is $whilenum
}

for (( whilenum=1; whilenum < 5; whilenum++ )); do
   case $whilenum in
   1)
      funct1
   ;;
   [23])
      for animal in dog bird turtle
      do
         echo $animal
      done
   ;;
   4)
      read -p "Enter your name: " username
      if [ ${#username} -gt  8 ] # or use if (( ${#username} > 8 ))
      then
         echo User name is long
      else
         echo User name is short
      fi
   ;;
   *)
      echo "The default will not be reached. Put an echo here for when someone changes the for-loop conditions."
   ;;
   esac
done
```

Comment: Thanks much for learning purposes I have to use a while loop to check if while num is equal 5 and increment at the bottom. Gonna apply the case statement while using the while loop to see what happens :)

Comment: if a case statement a conditional statement?

Comment: `case $var in something)` checks `if [ "$var" = something ]`, it is a short way for writing `if-then-else if-else if-- else-if. So yes, it is a sort of conditional statement.